# Unable to use the command Add or SubItems.Add

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.8

I'am trying to Add variables to the ListViewItem. It normally work with Windows Forms. Now i am trying to make it work with wpf. For some reason the function `Add` or `SubItems.Add` to `ListviewItem` doesn't work. If you wonder i do get data from the database. Any idea. Thanks already.

Using net 4.8

Error when hovering over Add: CS1061: 'ListViewItem' does not contain  definition for 'Add' and no accessible extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'ListviewItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using WPF_Application.Controller;
using WPF_Application.Model;
using WPF_Application.View;

namespace WPF_Application
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        VraagController vraagController = new VraagController();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           
            FillListView();
        }

        public void FillListView()
        {
            List<VraagModel> vraagList = vraagController.ReadAll();

            vragenLijst.Items.Clear();

            foreach (VraagModel item in vraagList)
            {
                //listview item aanmaken

                ListViewItem vraaglijst = new ListViewItem();
                vraaglijst.Parameters.AddWithValue(item.Vraagstelling);
                vraaglijst.Add(item.Correctantwoord);
                vraaglijst.Add(item.Meerkeuzevraag.Antwoord1);
                vraaglijst.Add(item.Meerkeuzevraag.Antwoord2);
                vraaglijst.Add(item.Meerkeuzevraag.Antwoord3);
                vraaglijst.Add(item.Meerkeuzevraag.Antwoord4);

                vraaglijst.Tag = item;

                vragenLijst.Items.Add(vraaglijst);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Application.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Application"
        Name="mainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Bedrijfsnaam" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Background="#F5F5F5" Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="131*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="669*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Background="White" Margin="25,40,25,15" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
            <TextBox Name="FilterTextBox"  Height="30" Width="200" Margin="25" VerticalAlignment="Top"  HorizontalAlignment="left" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E0E0E0" />
            <Button Height="30" Click="btnToevoegen" Content="Toevoegen" Width="100" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="5" Margin="0,25,130,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E0E0E0"  />
            <Button Height="30" Click="btnWijzigen" Content="Wijzigen" Width="100" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="5" Margin="0,25,235,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E0E0E0"  />
            <Button Height="30" Content="Verwijderen" Width="100" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="5" Margin="0,25,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#E0E0E0"  />
            <ListView Name="vragenLijst" BorderBrush="#cdcdcd" Margin="25,70,25,25" Padding="0">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn x:Name="Vraagstelling" Header="Vraagstelling" Width="200"/>
                        <GridViewColumn x:Name="Correctantwoord" Header="Correct antwoord" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn x:Name="Antwoord1" Header="Antwoord 1" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn x:Name="Antwoord2" Header="Antwoord 2" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn x:Name="Antwoord3" Header="Antwoord 3" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn x:Name="Antwoord4" Header="Antwoord 4" Width="100"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What error do you get when trying to add to the SubItems property?  ListViewItem itself is not a collection, it doesn't have an Add method.  SubItems is, but though you mentioned it I don't see any code using it.

Comment: Error when hovering over Add: CS1061: 'ListViewItem' does not contain  definition for 'Add' and no accessible extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'ListviewItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) @Tarazed

Comment: Yes, I expect that.  There is no Add method in ListViewItem.  Try ListViewItem.SubItems.Add().

Comment: I have tried: `vraaglijst.SubItems.Add(item.Vraagstelling);` Then i got the same error. Instead of `Add` it says `SubItems`. It looks like i maybe have the wrong using or not updated? maybe this helps. @Tarazed

Comment: There is no ListView.SubItems property and there is no ListView.Add property. the error message you get clearly states that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `ListViewItems.SubItems` property (this is not WinForms!) and there is no `ListViewItem.Add` property. The error message you get clearly states that:

> CS1061: 'ListViewItem' does not contain definition for 'Add'

There couldn't be a better error message.

When you are not sure about the class API you must consult the [.NET API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netframework-4.8) and lookup the e.g. [`ListView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listview?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) or [`ListViewItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listviewitem?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). In the properties section you can find all public properties.

Instead you must use the `ListView.ItemsSource` property.
This property holds the source collection that contains the items that the `ListView` (or `ItemsControl` in general) has to display.

To define the columns of the `GridView` you must set the `GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding` property to a property path that points to the associated property on the data item.

The .NET documentation also provides important topics that help to learn about the framework and particular controls. For example reading [Microsoft Docs: ListView Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/listview-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) would give you an idea how to use the `ListView` (for example how assign the data source or how to define the columns of the `GridView`).

```cs
public void FillListView()
{
  List<VraagModel> vraagList = vraagController.ReadAll();

  // Not required. Avoid the performance cost.
  //vragenLijst.Items.Clear();

  // Simply assign the IEnumerable to the ListView.ItemsSource
  vragenLijst.ItemsSource = vraagList;
}
```

```xml
<ListView Name="vragenLijst">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Vraagstelling" 
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Vraagstelling}" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Correct antwoord"
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Correctantwoord}" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Antwoord 1"
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Meerkeuzevraag.Antwoord1}" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Antwoord 2"
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Meerkeuzevraag.Antwoord2}" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Antwoord 3"
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Meerkeuzevraag.Antwoord3}" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Antwoord 4"
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Meerkeuzevraag.Antwoord4}" />
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Stupid of me to think that windows forms had the same syntax as wpf. I tried diffrent ways to achieve this. Thanks for your help!!!!!!!